# Display html code in browser in liferay search container

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay search container to display tables data. In one of the field, I need to display the HTML code as given. My question is How to Display html code in browser. My code is as follows.

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="question" name="Question" />
```

Comment: Try appending your value with `<code>` or `<pre>` tag, that will render HTML as text not components.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Question" >

<div class="question"><%= nameOfTheObjectInCollection.getQuestion() %></div>

</liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
```